# Problem involving conditional probability and random variables

Tags: probability

So, I was asked to solve the following problem:

"A production unit contains two machines functioning independently of each other. Each machine has reliability $p$ over the course of the day, so the probability of it breaking down is equal to $1-p$. In that case, it will be repaired during the night and will be in working order the next day. Only one machine can be repaired at once. Let $X_n$ denote the number of machines broken down at the start of the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ day, for $n = 1,2,$... Calculate the conditional probability $P(X_{n+1}=0 | X_n=0)$"

Here's my attempt. Since we're dealing with conditional probability, we can simply apply the definition, giving us: $$P(X_{n+1}=0 | X_n=0) = \frac{P(X_{n+1}=0 \ \land \ X_n=0)}{P(X_n = 0)}$$

I'm stuck there. Namely, because I don't know how to find $P(X_n=0)$ (i.e the probability that $0$ machines are broken down at the start of day $n$) because this also depends on what happened on the $n-1^{\mathrm{th}}$ day, and so on.

If you have any tips, or hints, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: You do not need to calculate $P(X_n=0)$.  Just assume $X_n=0$ and consider what then needs to happen to have $X_{n+1}\not = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is not always the go to tool.   As you observe, it is *not* a simple matter to find the terms involved here.   They are *harder* to evaluate.   So don't try that.

Go back to basics and look at what is being asked.   $\mathsf P(X_{n+1}=0\mid X_n=0)$ is the probability that no machines will be broken at the start of day $n+1$ when given that no machines were broken at the start of day $n$.

Such a state transition happens if *something or other* happens between those times.   Alternatively, if something *doesn't* happen.   Either way, what is the probability for that?

Comment: I got it (I think). If I let $F_n$ be the random variable that is equal to the number of machines which fail on the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ day, then I have $P(X_{n+1} = 0 | X_{n} = 0) = P(F_n = 0 \cup F_n = 1)$, which gives me $P(F_n= 0 | X_n = 0) + P(F_n=1|X_n=0) = p^2 +p(1-p)+(1-p)p$. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes. @Skyris  That is also $1-(1-p)^2$, the probability for not having two machines fail.